# Need to self sign a powershell script to use in the task manager

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, self-signed-certificate

I have a powershell script that if I open Powershell (right click> run as administrator) and post the code it works just fine. However when I try to create a task in task scheduler, the script will not work. I am assuming I need to sign the powershell script. I searched for a fix and came up with a Command that uses "makecert" however when I try to run it I get" 'makecert' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" in the program task arguments.

Comment: You are a genius! worked like a charm! thank you very much!